# Snowflake SQL wrap SHOW RESOURCE MOINTORS in SELECT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can one wrap the query `SHOW RESOURCE MOINTORS` in a SELECT statement to grab only a subset of the columns returned?

The following:

```
SELECT NAME, CREDIT_QUOTA, USED_CREDITS, REMAINING_CREDITS
FROM (SHOW RESOURCE MONITORS)
```

produces the error:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 6 unexpected 'SHOW'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For`SHOW` commands you need to use [RESULT SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan)

```
SHOW RESOURCE MONITORS
;

SELECT "name", "credit_quota", "used_credits", "remaining_credits"
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))    
;
```